# How can make the expansion to take effect in any type of file?

Tags: filetype, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

If I add the following lines in html.snippets:

```
snippet "(\S+)(\d+)" "Repeat token n times" r
`!p snip.rv = int(match.group(2)) * match.group(1)`
endsnippet
```

`#5` can expand to `#####`.

How can make the expansion to take effect in any type of file editing by Vim?

Comment: Based on your previous questions I tagged this as [tag:plugin-ultisnips], I assume that is correct? It's useful to specify *which* snippet plugin you're using, as there are many of them.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/1914ef242a5b6fc095abc4b2c7702d6697c69324/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L562),

> UltiSnips iterates
> over the snippet definition directories looking for files with names of the
> following patterns: ft.snippets, ft_*.snippets, or ft/*, ...

> The 'all' filetype is unique. It represents snippets available for use when
> editing any document regardless of the filetype

Thus instead of html.snippets, place the snippet definitions in one of the following:

- `all.snippets`
- `all_foo.snippets`
- `all/foo.snippets`

where `foo` could be anything you like.